# MinGW-w64 link assembly file to kernel32

Tags: windows, gcc, assembly, mingw, mingw-w64

I'm trying to use [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) to compile assembly code on Windows. The test code I am trying to compile is (I'm sure this code extremely bad, but the problem lies in the linker, not the actual code):

```
    .intel_syntax noprefix

    .text
    .globl  _start
_start:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    and rsp, -64
    sub rsp, 64
    mov rax, 0
    leave
    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4
```

And the command for I used for compiling is this:

```
gcc -nostdlib simpletest.s -o out.exe
```

It doesn't matter to the outcome if I add `-kernel32` at the end of the command or not.
No matter what I try I keep getting the following error:

```
Undefined reference to '_ExitProcess@4'
```

I should add that the same gcc is perfectly capable of compiling C code to assembly, and then compile that assembly code to an exe.

Comment: `call ExitProcess` seems to work for me though. Isn't the `@4` business only for 32 bit? Note that `push 0` is also wrong, the [64 bit calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) is different.

Comment: @Jester Thanks! I think I got it to work:D